# C++ for loop ends after input

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string name;
    string hometown;
    int age;
    int games;
    int* hours = new int [games];
};

int main(){
    int players;
    Student* s = new Student [players];

    cout << "How many esports players are there at TTU who major in csc?\n";
    cin >> players;
    cout << "\nPlease enter in information about each player: \n\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < players; i++){
        cout << "PLAYER " << (i + 1) << ":\n";
        cout << "\tNAME:\t";
        getline(cin >> ws, s[i].name);
        cout << "\tHOMETOWN:\t";
        getline(cin >> ws, s[i].hometown);
        cout << "\tAGE:\t";
        cin >> s[i].age;
        cout << "\tHOW MANY GAMES DOES " << s[i].name << " PLAY?\t";
        cin >> s[i].games;
            for(int j = 0; j < s[i].games; j++){
                cout << "NUMBER OF HOURS " << s[i].name << "PLAYED GAME"  << (j + 1) << "\t";
                cin >> s[i].hours[j];
            }
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, the for loop is ending after asking for age. I have tried with multiple inputs and it does the same thing. I am new to c++. Does anyone know why? Thank you for your time

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.  Your struct looks very sketchy to me, given how it default-allocates the `hours` array using an uninitialized member variable.  Run your program in a debugger so you get a breakpoint on the line of code that crashes (assuming this is a crash, which is very likely).  You are doing weird things also mixing line-based input with formatted stream input, but that's probably not the main issue right now.

Comment: Here, [let's look at the compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/s89143Tbd).  Turning on and reading compiler warnings can be much faster than asking for help.  What is the value of `players` at the line with `new Student [players]`?

Comment: *"the for loop is ending after asking for age."* -- More precisely, the **program** is ending (crashing) after asking for age. Before you jump to the conclusion that it's only the loop that's ending, you should test that hypothesis. Put some output after the loop, perhaps `cout << "Program done\n";` so that you can see the difference between the loop ending and the program ending. (Running in a debugger would be another way to see the difference.)

Comment: The `std::vector` class has officially existed in C++ for almost 24 years.  Why are persons still using `new[]`??

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie because teachers in almost every academic school doesn't allow to use them... and tend to inform students that they are ineffective surplus.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie -- I think 24 years is enough time to see that vectors are part of C++.  Or teach the students `C` and stop fooling them that they're learning C++.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie you're right, my professors always say to use 'new' and 'malloc'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not handling arrays correctly.  You are allocating them using uninitialized variables for their sizes:

- in `int games; int* hours = new int [games];`, `games` is uninitialized.
- in `int players; Student* s = new Student [players];`, `players` is uninitialized.

And, even if you were allocating the arrays correctly, you would be leaking them, since you are not freeing them when you are done using them.

When you need to use an array whose size is not known until runtime, you are correct to use `new[]`, but not until *after* you determine the size, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string name;
    string hometown;
    int age = 0;
    int games = 0;
    int* hours = nullptr;
};

int main(){
    cout << "How many esports players are there at TTU who major in csc?\n";

    int players;
    cin >> players;

    Student *s = new Student[players];

    cout << "\nPlease enter in information about each player: \n\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < players; ++i){
        cout << "PLAYER " << (i + 1) << ":\n";
        cout << "\tNAME:\t";
        getline(cin >> ws, s[i].name);
        cout << "\tHOMETOWN:\t";
        getline(cin >> ws, s[i].hometown);
        cout << "\tAGE:\t";
        cin >> s[i].age;
        cout << "\tHOW MANY GAMES DOES " << s[i].name << " PLAY?\t";
        cin >> s[i].games;
        s[i].hours = new int[s[i].games];
        for(int j = 0; j < s[i].games; ++j){
            cout << "NUMBER OF HOURS " << s[i].name << " PLAYED GAME " << (j + 1) << "\t";
            cin >> s[i].hours[j];
        }
    }

   // use player info as neded...

    for(int i = 0; i < players; ++i){
        delete[] s[i].hours;
    }
    delete[] s;

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, you should use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`/`delete[]` manually, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string name;
    string hometown;
    int age = 0;
    int games = 0;
    std::vector<int> hours;
};

int main(){
    cout << "How many esports players are there at TTU who major in csc?\n";

    int players;
    cin >> players;

    std::vector<Student> s(players);

    cout << "\nPlease enter in information about each player: \n\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < players; ++i){
        cout << "PLAYER " << (i + 1) << ":\n";
        cout << "\tNAME:\t";
        getline(cin >> ws, s[i].name);
        cout << "\tHOMETOWN:\t";
        getline(cin >> ws, s[i].hometown);
        cout << "\tAGE:\t";
        cin >> s[i].age;
        cout << "\tHOW MANY GAMES DOES " << s[i].name << " PLAY?\t";
        cin >> s[i].games;
        s[i].hours.resize(s[i].games);
        for(int j = 0; j < s[i].games; ++j){
            cout << "NUMBER OF HOURS " << s[i].name << " PLAYED GAME " << (j + 1) << "\t";
            cin >> s[i].hours[j];
        }
    } 

    // use player info as needed...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it. My professors keep telling me to use 'new' and 'malloc' but I see how vector is much more convenient

Comment: @tntcastle obviously, this can be solved using `new[]` and `malloc()` too (you really shouldn't be using `malloc()` in C++, though), but then you are responsible for freeing the memory manually when you are done using it. I have updated my answer to show this. But `std::vector` handles that for you.

Comment: @tntcastle the main problem with that is it's impossible to track which to use   after `delete` or `delete[]` unless you use RAII, i.e. you must write an analog of `std::vector`: structure should become non-trivial - get constructor and destructor - and allocate\reallocate\deallocate its memory. In C++ there is little use for `malloc`  without  placement `new` later.